# Google cloud endpoints service is not listed in api library

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to share my API (with a custom domain) with the customer( service consumer role), but this API is not listed in the API library. When he tries to open API using the link to generate API key he gots errors. The same problem I have when I try to generate API key for customers. I'm using endpoints frameworks for the GAE standard environment. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyjeE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one looks more like a problem with the Cloud console or the Cloud APIs, I'd better address the issue at a Public Issue Tracker (PIT), you can open one in [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=1162610), and preferably add a relevant [HAR file](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) that should contain some additional information of the response message.

This will help to correctly address any ongoing service issue.